# Why is my date comparison to the current date not working python

Tags: python, date

I think this is something simple but cannot figure it out. I have a string as a date that comes in as an argument in this format: 01/12/2017. I compare this with the current date: `now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`

The code:

```
if date <= now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"):
                        print(1)
```

Problem is if the current date is less than the date I pass in this still returns true.

I've googled and looks like this is the way to do it.

Comment: the date format isn't ISO: comparing date strings doesn't work!

Comment: hmm how can I get this to work with comparing a date that comes in as a string to the current date

Comment: parse the string instead of generating a string from a date. See linked answers

Comment: that works only with dates like `now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")` (year then month then day)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks I've changed this the linked answers show how to compare a strptime but now I have a strptime that I parsed my variable in and need to compare it to a strftime :/ shows an error of comparing wrong types :(

Comment: dont use `strftime`. Compare date objects instead.